# Is there a way to make a Seagate external hdd which never sleeps automatically go to sleep after a certain amount of time?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sleep

I have a portable Seagate hdd Backup Plus Slim. No matter how long it's connected without being used it never spins down and sleeps. It doesn't matter what device it's connected to. Even when it's connected to a laptop that's in sleep mode, the drive stays spinning forever. Only turning off the laptop completely or physically disconnecting the drive causes it to stop.

I think the drive must come configured to never sleep, ever. I don't know why a manufacturer would do this. From what I know that will reduce the lifespan of the drive. Plus because of it always spinning sometimes it sounds like it powers down harshly (there's a very audible sound of it suddenly shutting off, like the drive was spinning full speed when power cut off).

Is there a way to change this for a Seagate drive and make it so it sleeps? I think sleep after five minutes might be ideal for the way I use it.

The only question I found which was similar to this was for a Western Digital drive and the recommendation there was to use WD Drive Utilities. I don't imagine that  tool from another manufacturer could be used on a Seagate drive. That sounds like a risk of messing up the drive, or that it just wouldn't work in the first place.

To clarify, my goal is to get the external hdd itself to automatically sleep no matter what device it's connected to. Unless that can be done the problem isn't really solved.

It's often connected to a Wii for long periods of time for example and is constantly spinning the entire time the Wii is on, even when the hdd is not being used at all. This wasn't a problem with a previous drive because that drive would sleep.

Comment: you may wanna check out https://superuser.com/questions/318902/how-to-disable-power-to-usb-ports-when-laptop-is-in-sleep-mode

Comment: Unfortunately that would only marginally help. I added some more detail at the end to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but I posit you can use hdparm to change the drive to sleep, with a command like

```
  hdparm -B100 hdX
```

As per the manual, the number after "-B" represents

> "Get/set Advanced Power Management feature, if the drive supports
> it.  A  low  value  means aggressive power management and a high
> value means better performance.  Possible  settings  range  from
> values  1  through  127 (which permit spin-down), and values 128
> through 254 (which do not permit spin-down).  The highest degree
> of  power  management  is  attained with a setting of 1, and the
> highest I/O performance with a setting of 254.  A value  of  255
> tells  hdparm to disable Advanced Power Management altogether on
> the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most do).

hdX represents the drive, with X being a letter with "hda" = drive 1, "hdb"= drive 2 etc.

I've only ever used hdparm under Linux, but there is a Windows version.  Unfortunately I'm having difficulty locating an authoritative source for this, so I won't place a link.